# sed append path to end of specific line pattern search

Tags: sed

Would like to append path variables to end of line on a specific row with search pattern and append, **"Defaults    secure_path"** string I want to append: `:/etc/bla/foo/`

the file,

> filename

```
# asdf
# lkaj
# asdah

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## safdafdhdahdabfdabf
## Aedhadhfdahdahadhda
```

Tried pattern search for **"Defaults    secure_path"** and append to end of line:

```
sed '/^Defaults    secure_path = / s/$/ :/etc/bla/foo/' filename
```

But, got error:

```
sed -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: but sed never saved the file when editing with vim it never stuck.

Comment: You were almost there: 1) By default, `sed` outputs the stream to stdout. If you want to edit in place, check whether your `sed` version has the `-i` option to directly edit the file. 2) If your pattern contains a slash, use a different delimiter for the `s` command, for example: `s#$# :/etc/bla/foo#` 2.5) Is the whitespace near the colon intentionally?

Comment: Are you trying to edit `/etc/sudoers` with `sed`? I really wouldn't do that - it's way way too easy to break the configuration - and therefore the command - if you get it even slightly wrong. Use the interactive `visudo` instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can use awk command and append it.

```
bash-4.1$ cat filename
# asdf
# lkaj
# asdah

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## safdafdhdahdabfdabf
## Aedhadhfdahdahadhda
bash-4.1$
bash-4.1$ awk '$0~/Defaults.*secure_path/{$0=$0":/etc/bla/foo/"}1' filename
# asdf
# lkaj
# asdah

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/etc/bla/foo/

## safdafdhdahdabfdabf
## Aedhadhfdahdahadhda
```

this awk command search for the pattern "Defaults" and append the value at end of the line.

using **sed** command

```
bash-4.1$ sed "s?\(Defaults.*secure_path.*\)?\1:/etc/bla/foo/?" filename
# asdf
# lkaj
# asdah

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/etc/bla/foo/

## safdafdhdahdabfdabf
## Aedhadhfdahdahadhda
```

Comment: found out that **sed -i** option saves the text

Comment: This answer can lead corruption to /etc/sudoers file. I did some small change on suggested solution so it cannot corrupt the file.